# Speed up issues with 4 threads on quadcore system using OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a speed up problem using 4 threads on quadcore system using OpenMP. With 2 threads the efficiency is close to 1 but with 4 threads it reduces to half that is the running time is more or less same as when running the code using 2 threads. I searched on OpenMP forum and i find similar issue before which is because of Inter turbo boost technology. Please refer to this post http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1289&start=0&hilit=intel+turbo+boost

So i have tried to disable turbo boost on all the 4 processors of my machine but couldn't get rid of the problem.

I took the benchmark code from above link only.

I have a DELL laptop and my harware/OS information summary is as follows:

```
OS : Linux3.0.0.12-generic , Ubuntu
KDE SC Version : 4.7.1

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

Please let me know what could be other possible problems that is not allowing me to speed up using 4 threads/cores. As an additional info. i have checked that all the 4 threads are running on different cores.

Looking forward to your answers.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>


double estimate_pi(double radius, int nsteps){

   int i;
   double h=2*radius/nsteps;
   double sum=0;
   for (i=1;i<nsteps;i++){
      sum+=sqrt(pow(radius,2)-pow(-radius+i*h,2));
      //sum+=.5*sum;
   }
   sum*=h;
   sum=2*sum/(radius*radius);
   //printf("radius:%f --> %f\n",radius,sum);
   return sum;


}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


   double ser_est,par_est;
   long int radii_range;
   if (argc>1) radii_range=atoi(argv[1]);
   else radii_range=500;   

   int nthreads;
   if (argc>2) nthreads=atoi(argv[2]);
   else nthreads=omp_get_num_procs();

   printf("Estimating Pi by averaging %ld estimates.\n",radii_range);
   printf("OpenMP says there are %d processors available.\n",omp_get_num_procs());

   int r;
   double start, stop, serial_time, par_time;



   par_est=0;
   double tmp=0;
   ser_est=0;
   start=omp_get_wtime();
   for (r=1;r<=radii_range;r++){
      tmp=estimate_pi(r,1e6);
      ser_est+=tmp;
   }
   stop=omp_get_wtime();
   serial_time=stop-start;
   ser_est=ser_est/radii_range;

   omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
   start=omp_get_wtime();
   #pragma omp parallel for private(r,tmp) reduction(+:par_est)
   for (r=1;r<=radii_range;r++){
      tmp=estimate_pi(r,1e6);
      par_est+=tmp;
   }
   stop=omp_get_wtime();
   par_time=stop-start;
   par_est=par_est/radii_range;

   printf("Serial Estimate: %f\nParallel Estimate:%f\n\n",ser_est,par_est);
   printf("Serial Time: %f\nParallel Time:%f\nNumber of Threads: %d\nSpeedup: %f\nEfficiency: %f\n",serial_time,par_time,nthreads,serial_time/par_time, serial_time/par_time/nthreads);


}
```

Comment: @KillianDS: I've copied his code from that forum post here.

Comment: @Tudor: I was under the impression that was an old forum post and not the actual code of the OP here.

Comment: @KillianDS: Hmm, I see now that it's from 2011. But why did he reference it then?

Comment: @Tudor: Actually i was just looking at solution to my prob. and then i find this post with better benchmark code then mine, so i given the reference to the code an post..neways many thanks for your answer..I didn't know my machine is dual-core with HT..

Answer (score 5):

The [Core i7-2620M](http://ark.intel.com/products/52231/Intel-Core-i7-2620M-Processor-%284M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz%29) is a dual-core with HT (thus 4 logical cores). HT will not always improve program performance and the improvement depends a lot on the program itself (for some memory-intensive apps it may even degrade). You should definitely not expect a 4x speedup, since it does not have 4 physical cores.

If you have time it's worth to read a bit from here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-insights-to-intel-hyper-threading-technology/

Comment: So, having 4 threads would not decrease the performance compared to 2 threads with i7's speciality. What about 6 threads? Would it decrease?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: With 6 threads you are already exceeding the number of concurrent threads, although 2 extra threads may not be enough to degrade performance. Again, it depends a lot on the app.

Comment: @Tudor: Actually, HT can make memory intensive applications faster, while non memory intensive application might be a bit slower with HT.

Comment: @ronag: If there is too much contention on the bus there will definitely be a performance hit.

Comment: @Tudor: What? You have give more of a context to such a comment. HT is faster when application threads are often stalled, which can be caused by cache misses (memory intensive) or branch misspredictions.

Comment: @ronag: Your statement rarely applies to threads of the same app doing the same computations. Usually they will all be stalled at the same time or perform memory requests at the same time.

Comment: @Tudor: Sorry, but your comment makes no sense. Whether threads run in the same application or not is irrelevant. If I have a parallel for loop that reads a lot from memory, then running with HT will make that faster than without HT.

Comment: @ronag: It will make if faster in parallel on different cores (again debatable), but due to the features of HT it may become slower in fact. I have several test programs that can prove this. If you have 4 threads sharing an array and doing computations at the same time, if the data is not in cache they will all be stalled when retrieving their respective chunks don't you agree?

Comment: @ronag: Now assuming that cache sizes stay the same and you decide to double the amount of data in the array since you have 2 more threads from HT, you might see that in fact the two threads running on the same core will evict each other's data from the shared cache.

Comment: @Tudor: That depends entirely on how the application uses the cache. E.g. if the parallel for loop only reads each value once (i.e. doesn't re use values in the cache) then it doesn't matter if the threads evict eachothers cache, since they will not use it anyway. I would suggest you read the document you linked.

Comment: @ronag: I'm speaking about linear access obviously. Accessing one value out of a cache line is a stupid idea even in a sequential program.

Comment: @Tudor: I'm curious, from your understanding how exactly would HT bring any performance improvements.

Comment: @Tudor: It seems to me we are talking about different things/scenarios. Though I'm not sure what you are talking about. If you would to perform parallel computation on a data set, you would usually let each hardware thread work sequentially on separate partitions of the data in parallel. With HT, while one thread is stalled due to e.g. a cache miss, another thread can work.

Comment: @ronag: IMO, It could bring improvements generally when you have processes running independently in the OS and, as you said, in case of stalling it allows for a higher degree of parallelism among them. You could also see it inside the same app, provided that threads do not collide too much on the shared components of the single core.

Comment: @Tudor: Yes? Where exactly is your disagreement with me? A single application where threads are often stalled can work faster with HT.

Comment: @ronag: Sure it could also work in that case, though generally if the instructions are uniform across threads (they all access data from the array at the same time) and the array is not in cache, then they will all stall waiting for data to be fetched from their chunk. That's my point.

Comment: @ronag: Often stalled yes, but not stalled at the same time, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @Tudor: Agreed. However, due to the pipelined and out of order execution nature of CPU hardware, stalling of hardware threads at the exact same time is not very common.

Comment: @ronag: Sure. It all depends on how often the threads issue memory reads.